# Pandas to_csv() creating strange-looking table

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

Im parsing one website and saving data as .csv table. But when I opened my .csv file with Excel, I saw lots of strange symbols.
[image]

Also after saving it into .xlsx and converting to .csv I saw the same table. Is it ok? Or how should I fix that?
Here's my table creating code:

```
data.to_csv('./data.csv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
```

And here's original .xlsx data:

[image]

(Its not strange symbols, just russian)

Comment: What does the original `data` look like.

Comment: It may be a problem with the encoding of the data, can you show us the original one ?

Comment: @MhamedBendenia I added original data pic

Comment: Perhaps you should set your locale in the Python code - https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are from Russia.
Excel with regional settings by default tries to open CSV files encoded with 1251 codepage.
So you can

- save with 1251 codepage
  or
- save as txt and choose UTF-8 when open it.

Comment: I changed encoding to cp1251 and it helped, thank you